# The intended way to reauthenticate with Twitterizer2

Tags: c#, twitterizer

I've got a problem where i've been working in TweetSharp on a project, and found it had some limitations i couldn't overcome. Done some research and found Twitterizer can do what I want.

I'm having some trouble working out how i re-authenticate with Twitterizer after caching the Access token and access token secret after the application's been authorized once. Should i be caching that info? Is there more info i need to re-authenticate again? Am i doing it wrong and If someone could let me know what i SHOULD be doing to re-authenticate that'd be grand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that caching the Access Token and sending it along with future requests is literally all that needs to be done. You can assign the tokens their values from a saved cache, the feilds are not read only.